# How to download WMS Layer data from Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms, maptiler

I am displaying the WMS data layer on the leaflet map, Now I want to make a "Download" button from where user can download the specific data of WMS layer (not all data).

I have displayed the WMS layer data on leaflet and now want to download the data from leaflet maps but I do not know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

MapTiler Cloud (WMS layers) maps are not intended for any download or offline usage.